# androidのwebviewのkeyboardが消えない

Tags: android, java, android-studio, webview

http://dotinstall.com/lessons/browser_android_v2/32604
上記のサイトの通りにコードを書きましたが、エミュレーターで表示すると、キーボートがデフォルトで出現していて、edittextのフォーカスを外しても消えません。
キーボードを非表示にするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

ソフトキーボードを非表示にするは`ユーザーが非表示にする`もしくは`アプリにフォーカスが外れた時(など)に非表示にするコードを書いておく`必要があります。

例えばフォーカスが外れた時にキーボードを非表示にするリスナーは以下のように書きます。

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener focusLostSoftKeyboardHide = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
};
```